# why java long type calculate different?

Tags: java, integer, long-integer

```
final long b = 123123;
final long c = 123123*123123*123123;
long d = b*b*b;
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(d);
```

output :
-162426261
1866455185461867

In the case of the first printout, it seems that overflow occurs because Java treats it as an integer rather than a long one, but why is it not calculated as an integer in the second case? I thought that if I put final in front of long and make it a constant, it would be calculated in compile time, so I thought that the second and first output sentences should have the same result, but I want to know why I was wrong.

Comment: "why is it not calculated as an integer in the second case" Because `b` is a `long`.

Comment: And because `123123` is an `int` literal.  Try changing `123123` to `123123L` in the expression for the value of `c`.

Comment: To make the second line multiply `long` integers, make at least the first constant a long: `123123L*123123*123123`.  Note the "L".

Answer (score 2):

Because numeric literals without a decimal point in Java treated as `int`, variable `c` gets initialized with an overflown result of `int` multiplication.

Conversely, variable `d` is assigned to a result of multiplication that is done on `long` values (because `b` is of type `long`).

Basically you have:

```
long c = int * int * int;     // multiply `int` numbers and then promote an overflown result into `long`
long d = long * long * long;
```

> I thought that if I put final in front of long and make it a constant, it would be calculated in compile time

Variables `b` and `c` are compile-time constants, because they are primitive, marked as final, assigned at the moment of declaration and initialized with constant expressions. All accuracies of these variables in the code would be replaced with their values. But it doesn't change how the value of `c` is calculated.

Variable `d` isn't a compile-time constant because it has no `final` modifier. But this fact also has no effect on the way how its value is calculated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer first. My question is, "The Java compiler is available to calculate expressions that contain constant variables and certificate operators duration code compilation," and I thought that if the long variable 'd' is calculated in compile time, the overflow should occur the same way, because it recognizes 'b' as int.
Isn't the long 'd' calculation happening at compilation time?

Comment: @bca `b` is **not** an `int`, you've provided its value as `int`, but it's stored as `long` because you've declared that `b` is of type `logn`, it would occupy `8` bytes, not `4`. And the result of arithmetic operations done on `long` would also be `long`.

Answer (score 1):

Since your value of c won't contain decimal points, it will be treated as an int. To solve this just add "L"(L stands for long)

```
final long c = 123123L*123123L*123123L;
```

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      final long b = 123123;
      final long c = 123123L*123123L*123123L;
      long d = b*b*b;
      System.out.println(c);
      System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

Output

```
1866455185461867
1866455185461867
```